# Android Youtube App Hint Circle

Tags: android, youtube, geometry, hint, showcaseview

I am trying to add a hint circle into my app, I implemented [Showcase View library](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) but it does not operate like the actual hint circle used in the Youtube App. The Youtube App blurs the background activity so the content is not visible while the Showcase View does not, which in turns creates a very messy overlay. Below are links to each screenshot.

[Youtube](http://i1360.photobucket.com/albums/r651/rmass94/App/Screenshot_2013-10-03-21-15-44_zps25a1390a.png)
[Showcase View](https://raw.github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView/master/example.png)

Comment: both links are the same image now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that Youtube blurs the background (something which is notoriously difficult to do in Android), rather it uses a very dark background color with a high opacity. This is possible in ShowcaseView using the `sv_backgroundColor` theme attribute. The [example app](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView/blob/master/sample/res/values/styles.xml) shows how this can be done.

Comment: Thank you, I did not see you could theme the Showcase View.

Comment: Yeah, afraid the documentation is a bit lacking - definitely a fault on my part. I'll get round to it eventually!